# Increment Table with button

Tags: c#, asp.net, auto-increment

I have table and button ,I want to increment that table with click of button,How can i achieve this?

My Table is Similar to this

`<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
Information
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
city
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
state
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="tState" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
zip
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="tZip" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
</td></tr></table>
<asp:LinkButton ID="AddNew" runat="server" />`

Example

```
                 Information
          City       ---------
          State      ---------
          Zip        ---------
                  Add New Button
```

After Click on Button I want

```
                Information
          City       ---------
          State      ---------
          Zip        ---------
                Information
          City       ----------
          State      ---------
          Zip        ---------
                 Add New Button
```

I try with Gridview But I don't know logic and I also Google this But Dont find anything.
+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do sounds easy in theory, but it isn't that easy in practice.
You have to create controls dynamically in your button click event, add them to the page, and recreate them OnInit to get the viewstate bound to them.

You should read about dynamic controls in ASP.NET: https://web.archive.org/web/20211031102347/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What makes this a little tricky is that you're mixing client side controls (i.e. `table`) and server side controls (`asp:textbox`).  If you were to make that table `runat="server"` you could then add a click handler to your button and in the code-behind to programatically add new `TableRow`s and `TableCell`s with whatever contents you would like.